# PHP - file_exists doesn't work even if file exists in directory

Tags: php, file, find, file-exists

Im trying to verify if file exists in directory. When I use this code it works - image is displayed:

```
<?php 

  $imgId=0; 
  $filename='../uploadedimages/project-'.$item->id.'-'.$imgId;

  echo "<img src='".$filename."' ></img>";

?>
```

When I use the same code with file_exists function, it doesn't work:

```
<?php 

  $imgId=0; 
  $filename='../uploadedimages/project-'.$item->id.'-'.$imgId;

  if (file_exists($filename)) {                             
    echo "<img src='".$filename."' ></img>";                
  }

?>
```

My question is simple: WTF??

Comment: Your documentroot is not the same as the server documentroot... So `file_exists()` uses the folder where the script resides in as the reference directory. Loading the `<img>` takes it referenced from the root of your webserver.

Comment: `file_exists` expects the filesystem path.

Comment: Sidenote: `</img>` you don't need that.

Comment: Also relative path's are a pain to calculate for a server

Comment: Read the *"WTF"* manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php ;) `$filename='/var/user/you/httpdocs/uploadedimages/project...`

Comment: I though this is filesystem path. What is filesystem path then?

Comment: `$filename='/var/user/you/httpdocs/uploadedimages/project...` <= *that*.

Comment: Z:\kvetena.local\web\uploadedimages\ - this is my current filepath, but it can be changed in future. What should I do then?

Comment: Run phpinfo() it will give you your system path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to know where you are.

And then try something like this:

```
$filename=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'uploadedimages/project-'.$item->id.'-'.$imgId;
```

But first you need to make sure the path exist.

Answer (score 0):

on linux server, try to change file access permission to 755 before using file_exists function

**chmod 755 filename.ext**